# using media-queries for values change in sass variables

Tags: variables, sass, media-queries

what i want to do is basically this:

```
    @media all and (min-width: 700px) {
$dimension:96px;
$dimension-white:76px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
$dimension:76px;
$dimension-white:56px;
}
```

is it possible to assign different values to scss variables based on media-queries?
thank you much!

Comment: sorry for the copy and paste but it wouldnt let me post :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though this is a dupe, the answer is no. Media queries are handled by the browser and SASS variables are handled by, you guessed it, SASS.

What you have here would probably get compiled as-is into your stylesheet and break it or not get compiled at all. I haven't tried it because it just doesn't work.

Comment: Dupes don't need answers, they're supposed to get closed.

Comment: Ok, then it will get closed?

Comment: Eventually (in theory).  Moderation is slow in [sass].  Don't feel that you need to delete your answer, just refrain from answering dupes in the future.